# How to write inside a file at specific position using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I am building an interactive CLI project generator and I want to have a similar feature like angular CLI have.

Although I am working on to generate folders and files but I am not sure that how can I write inside a file at a specific position.

Suppose, when we generate a component using angular cli, it registers the component inside our modules file. So how can I write inside a file at specific location? Say if I want to include a require tag in node inside a file how would I do it? How would I know at what position the imports are ending and at what position do I include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create simple CLI using REPL module in Node.js
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/repl.html

For creating folders/files you could use `fs` module
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html

For running external commands (like `git init`), you could use child_process module (exec method)
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: Hey @Eugene, thanks for answering!

Suppose I have 2 different files and folders structure with codes in it which are linking them together that I want to create based on users command. What will be the best option to do that? Should I pre-create those files and folders and then just copy paste it into the directory when user commands or should I create it dynamically with content? Or do we have other options to do that?

Comment: I would add it dynamically using `fs` module.
Regarding different content  - I would create the file - content.json. In this file you will have such object: 

`{key1: content1, key2: content2};`

Using `fs` module you could read the `content.json`, find content which you need and create a file using the content

Comment: Hey @Eugene I have update the question please have a look at it.